# HTML/CSS: How to prevent Android and iPhone browsers from upscaling background images

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, media-queries

I have a problem in mobile browsers with the use of media queries in compination with background images

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

The meta tag above is needed for the mobile browsers to react to the media queries (otherwise the browsers pretends it has a larger screen and downscales the page), the problem is that this meta tag when used also scales up all the background images on the site. This totally breaks the design of the page.

I want all of the browsers to represent every element of the page in the scale 1:1.

How can I make the media queries work but prevent the browser from upscaling background images in the page. In short I want the page to be treated the same as in a desktop browser.

The same problems occurs in both Android and iPhone browsers.

Comment: Why is it that the browsers that runs on units with high DPI scales up only SOME elements and not the WHOLE page?? This is bound to introduce problems, this is the IE problematic all over again!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using fixed **background-size** property, eg. `background-size:100px 100px;`

Comment: Yes, the problem with that is that I suddenly have to always specify that on every element that has a background image, it seems like the wrong end to start in. Can't I just prevent the browser from scaling them in the first place?

Comment: Does anyone have any other solution, one that completely disables this browser scaling?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use scaling in your meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```